# Cake PHP making groups private

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am using cakephp and am new to it. I have created public and private groups in my website. How do i make sure only members can view the content of private groups and not everyone. 
The SQL Tables are - 
*Users-*

```
  id
    created 
    modified 
    email
    password
```

*Groups-*

```
  id 
    name
    type - has value 1 if group is private and 0 if group is public
```

*Groups_Users*

```
 id 
   group_id
   user_id
   created 
   modified
```

Please if someone can explain. Thank You

Comment: I think we need more information because you have many posibilities to do this, can you post the complete database or at least the tables where are stored the content of your groups ?

Comment: I'd suggest you start with the documentation and check back once you have a specific question! **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ACL ? if so you can create a "private" group & a method allowed to users belonging to that group (you can enhance it with routing prefix, but that's another subject)

It's as simple as : create method that fetch content -> create group -> give access rights to that group & that's it, only users belonging to that group can access that method.

If you're not using ACL, i suggest you to learn more about it it's time well spent. There's plugins which make it really easy to work with them & if you need more control you can create your own Authorization process.